# How to compare 2 list for object detection

Tags: python, python-3.x, opencv

I have made a function that detects a object on screen using opencv matchTemplate and returns its center locations as (x, y).
I want to compare the results of running the same function on 2 different objects to detect the location of one object in reference of the other. In my case the two objects are a player avatar and some bushes I want to know is the player currently standing near a bush or not.There is only one user avatar on screen therefore it only returns single (x, y) value for it but there are multiple bushes therefore multiple (x, y) values. I want a way to compare those two matrices. Sorry about the code format.

```
def center(base_img, needle_img, th, color):
result = cv.matchTemplate(BASE_IMG, needle_img, cv.TM_CCOEFF_NORMED)
threshold = th
yloc, xloc = np.where(result >= threshold)
w = needle_img.shape[1]
h = needle_img.shape[0]
rectangles = []
for (x, y) in zip(xloc, yloc):
    rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)])
    rectangles.append([int(x), int(y), int(w), int(h)])
rectangles, weights = cv.groupRectangles(rectangles, 1, 0.4)
points = []
for (x, y, w, h) in rectangles:
    certre_x = x + int(w / 2)
    certre_y = y + int(h / 2)
    cv.drawMarker(base_img, (certre_x, certre_y), color, cv.MARKER_DIAMOND)
    points.append((certre_x, certre_y))
    # cv.imshow("result", base_img)
    # print(points)
    # return points
```

Comment: You can loop through the center of the bushes and get the distance to each bush  sqrt(( x2-x1)**2 + ( y2-y1)**2) or you could use nearest neighbor and numpy https://towardsdatascience.com/k-nearest-neighbors-classification-from-scratch-with-numpy-cb222ecfeac1

Comment: thanks alot @Cary H the first method worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You can loop through the center of the bushes and get the distance to each bush sqrt(( x2-x1)**2 + ( y2-y1)**2) or you could use nearest neighbor and numpy.

Post a code snippet if it worked.